# Is a zero mean curvature submanifold, with a flat open subset, flat everywhere?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature

Let $\Sigma \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ be a complete and connected minimal submanifold (with or without boundary), i.e. its mean curvature $H$ vanishes everywhere. 
Assume also that there exists an open subset $A \subset \Sigma$ contained in a hyperplane, i.e. where the second fundamental form vanishes.

Can we say that the second fundamental form vanishes everywhere in $\Sigma$ ?

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Do you know that minimal submanifolds are real analytic?

Comment: @MoisheCohen I can believe it, since the strong relation between minimal surfaces and harmonic functions, but I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

Lemma 1 [here](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1214431489): Minimal submanifolds are real analytic.